# C# Mixed Unsafe/Safe Library

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm slowly building a code libary for use across several applications.  Some of the code is processing images and pre-existing message formats (converted from C++) so unsafe code is required.

Any reasons why I should NOT generally mix unsafe and safe code in the same library assembly any more than I have to?

To put it another way: should I maintain a purely safe library and collect unsafe code into a different library/libraries?

I appreciate that there are trust issues to consider with 'unsafe' libraries but since those functions are critical to most of my applications, does it really matter?  Either all of my code, safe & unsafe, is trusted or it isn't trusted and my application won't run.  Or am I missing the point?

Comment: "so unsafe code is required" I wouldnt be so sure about that just yet. You'll find that with a little 'out-of-the-box' thinking you can pretty much convert old C++ code to safe C# code.

Comment: True. On the other hand I've got several cases of C/C++ code that does encryption and data formatting that I'd rather not mess around with too much. This code heavily relies on pointer handling so when converting into C# I have to move into the realms of unsafe code to port with minimum changes. FWIW I think reading a byte array off a memory stream is a fairly good way of stepping through data in memory.

Comment: Also when dealing with pixel data directly in bitmaps the advice seems to be, for better performance, to get the pixel data into a BitmapInfo object and step through pixels via a pointer in unsafe code.  Anyway that's the code I have at the moment.  Maybe one day I'll find some time to re-implement in a safe way ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299337/should-i-mingle-my-safe-code-with-my-unsafe-code

Answer (score 4):

In theory you can develop in safe code what you need, but let's assume that you have good reasons to use unsafe code :)

In the parts of code that you run unsafe code you risk of forgetting to deallocate memory, etc... so if you manage memory well you should not have a problem. When you have a C# project using COM+ dlls you are doing it all the time. In your case is better because you own all the code so you can fix any memory leak if you are able to detect it.

If you collect all unsafe code in a separate library

**PROS**

- You can create a new safe library in the future
- If you see that dll failing on execution logs you will be able to isolate easier the source of problem.

**CONS**

- Worst readability of your code if you have to split safe/unsafe code in a unnatural way.

So to be honest decision is yours. If I were you I will split unsafe code into a different project to have the ability of replacing it with safe code if it happens to be needed.